# Variable types of videos and images

Tags: android

Am working on some application. However, i have finished two modules which invoke the phones' native camera to take a snapshot and an also record a video. I intend to use the phone application to send the image and the video taken and recorded by the phone to a website i intend to create. However, for textual information, i could store the information as strings, for the image and the video, i am not sure if i should leave them as Uris upon submission. Below is my picture, and video programs respectively. Thanx
Picture code:

```
package com.project;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPicture extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    /*constant and variable created so as to work with the taken pictures*/
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    Uri imageUri;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pic);
        Button pictureButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pictureButton);
        pictureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.jpg");
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            //do something about the image in the in outputFileUri
            Toast.makeText(MyPicture.this,
                    "Picture successfully taken",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MyPicture.this,/*program execution proceeds back to MyPicture, our start page after success of image takin*/
                            Myindex.class);
                    startActivity(i);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MyPicture.this,
                    "Picture Unsuccessfully taken",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MyPicture.this,/*program execution proceeds back to MyPicture, so we can redo the recording*/
                            MyPicture.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Video code:

```
package com.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyVideo extends Activity {
    /*program for the vid button*/
    private static int  RECORD_VIDEO = 1;
    private static int HIGH_VIDEO_QUALITY = 1;
    //private static int MMS_VIDEO_QUALITY = 0;
    Uri recordedVideo;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vid);
        Button videoButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.videoButton);
        videoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, HIGH_VIDEO_QUALITY);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RECORD_VIDEO);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == RECORD_VIDEO){
            recordedVideo = data.getData();
            //to do something with the recorded video
            //we shall insert this information in the database
            Toast.makeText(MyVideo.this,
                    "Video successfully recorded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MyVideo.this,/*program execution proceeds back to Myindex, our start page*/
                            Myindex.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            /*Happens after unsuccessfull recording of video*/
            Toast.makeText(MyVideo.this,
                    "Video Unsuccessfully recorded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MyVideo.this,/*program execution proceeds back to MyVideo, so we can redo the recording*/
                            MyVideo.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For images what I usually do is to decode the data as a `Bitmap`and then I send it via Http Post using the multipart content-type.

You can decode the image file as a `Bitmap` using: [BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29).

Here is an example of how I send the `Bitmap` with multipart using the [Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/dependencies.html) library:

```
public String doHttpMultipart(String url, 
                                  List<NameValuePair> pairs,
                                  Bitmap bitmap,
                                  String fileName) throws IOException, 
                                                ClientProtocolException,
                                                UnsupportedEncodingException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(imageData, fileName);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = 
                        new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            reqEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);

            for(NameValuePair p : pairs) {
                reqEntity.addPart(p.getName(), new StringBody(p.getValue()));
            }

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);

            String response = "";
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
                response = super.readHttpStream(response, in, httpResponse);    
            } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new IOException();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
```

For a video file, it should be the same you should see how to decode it as an array of bytes and send it with multipart.